# Vaadin 23.2.5 and flow-server

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

Vaadin recently updated to `Vaadin 23.2.5` but I can't find the corresponding `flow-server` dependency of the same version:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>flow-server</artifactId>
        <version>23.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

So my question is - is this a good idea to use new `Vaadin 23.2.5` with `flow-server 23.2.4` dependency? I need this dependency for one of my backend module for `com.vaadin.flow.shared.Registration;` and `com.vaadin.flow.component.UIDetachedException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Vaadin BOM in your Dependency Management to always get matching and tested combination of artefacts provided by Vaadin - for example `flow-server` or components.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
  <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
  <version>VERSION</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```